# Как копировать историю, текущие разрешения и сохраненные данные сайтов в Хроме, если они не копируются?

Tags: google-chrome, copy

Я бы хотел скопировать историю браузера (т.е. не официально через Гугл или его сервисы) и, в частности, "текущие разрешения и сохраненные данные сайтов". Пробовал скачать HTML страницу, но она не содержит ничего, кроме стилей и бесполезных html тегов - пустышка.
Кажется, если я вижу текст на своем экране, то он уже на моей машине, а значит я могу его достать и сохранить в более удобной форме (скажем, в текстовом файле). Но я не знаю как.

Принципиальное ограничение - не использовать никаких официальных средств от Гугл или его сервисов, но возможно использование сторонних программ.

Comment: У  вас наверняка теги прогружаеться в js , тут один выход. Реализовать всё через selenium

Comment: `если я вижу текст на своем экране, то он уже на моей машине` - текст вы и видите (но он вам не нужен). Данные сайтов ищите в куках `document.cookie`, история хранится в браузере (а не на странице)  и доступ к ней ограничен конфиденциальностью

Comment: можно поподробнее, как получить данные из куки файлов?